# sort a yyyy/mm column correctly in google sheet (1991/10 is always after 1991/01)

Tags: google-sheets

There is a [google sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZDHAx2ckvhtrSM3n6WtfBktb5HHVMSNjxAjhZKis4lU/edit?usp=sharing) and try to calculate the monthly average price using the daily price in the Column A & B

Column C tries to get the mm/yyyy

[image]

Trying to sort the column E average monthly price by the column D mm/yyyy after calculating the monthly average of the price using the formula

```
=QUERY(B2:C,"select C, avg(B) group by C Order By C ASC")
```

But in the mm/yyyy column D,

1991/10, 1991/11, 1991/12 is always after 1991/01

Using the sort range result in the same sorting result. nothing changed.

[image]

Curious how can we correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the formula in column C with
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A <> "", YEAR(A3:A) & "/" & TEXT(MONTH(A3:A), "00"), ""))`

This should pad the months with leading zeros, and allow lexical sorting to work properly.